# Python very slow as compared to Java for this algorithm

Tags: java, python, performance

I'm studying algorithms and decided to port the Java Programs from the textbook to Python, since I dislike the Java overhead, especially for small programs, and as an exercise.

The algorithm itself is very simple, It just takes all triplets out of an array, in a bruteforce kinda way, and counts how many of the triplets sum up to zero (eg: [-2,7,-5])

```
 public static int count(int[] a) {
        int N = a.length;
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++) {
                for (int k = j+1; k < N; k++) {
                    if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0) {
                        cnt++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }
```

I ported it to :

```
def count(a):
    cnt = 0
    ln = len(a)
    for i in xrange(0,ln): 
        for j in xrange(i + 1,ln):
            for k in xrange(j + 1,ln): 
                if a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0:
                    cnt+=1
    return cnt
```

Now measuring just these functions are taking :

```
java :   array of 2000 elements --> 3 seconds 
python : array of 2000 elements --> 2 minutes, 19 seconds

UPDATE 
python (pypy) : array of 2000 elements --> 4 seconds ( :-) )
```

Of course this is not a good algorithm, it just goes to show, both here and in the textbook.  I have done some programming both in Java and Python before, but was not aware of this huge difference.

The question boils down to : how te overcome this?  More specifically :

1. Is this code a good port, or am I missing something trivial?
2. Is switching to another runtime Jython for example a solution?  Is it easy to keep my codebase in eclipse and just add an interpreter (compiler?) ? Or will switching to another interpreter/compiler only make things slightly better?

Right now I am using python 2.7.3 and Java 1.7 32ibts on windows 7.

I know there are similar questions out there on SO about java/python performance, but the answers like there are different runtime environments for python out there are not helpfull for me at the moment.

What I want to know is if some of these runtimes can close this huge gap and are worth epxloring?

UPDATE :

I installed pypy and the differences now are enormous...

UPDATE 2 :

Some very interesting things I noticed : the islice method in an answer here is faster on 'regular' python, but a lot slower on pypy.  Even so, pypy still remains a lot faster using no matter it uses regular loops or islices in this algoritm

As Bakuriu notices in a remark runtime environments can matter a whole lot, but a runtime environment faster for this algoritm is not necessarily faster for any algoritm...

Comment: <joke>That's quite a Java overhead over python: -2 minutes and 21 seconds: 1/48 times slower/joke>

Comment: try xrange instead of range in python 2.7 first, you could also use the lib numpy for numerical computations, this should give you a perfomance boost, but usually python isn't the first choice for perfomance

Comment: Your port is bad. On Python 2.7.3, `range()` will create intermediate lists, and since the loops are nested three levels deep, there'll be a LOT of them. Use Python 3.x, or use `xrange()`, or try iterating over an [`islice`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Comment: @Eugenie, Just tried it, but no gain I am afraid

Comment: @millimoose : xrange is not the solution I am afraid, I will adapt the port and the time in the question with xrange (5 second gain)

Comment: You are using the wrong approach in porting the algorithm - using a more pythonic approach would probably be way faster. In this case, you could use slices, sum and a generator expression to replace your nested for loops: `cnt = sum(1 for x in xrange(0, ln-3) if not sum(a[x:x+3]))`

Comment: @l4mpi The code you wrote in the comment solves a much easier problem. The OP is not looking for consecutive elements.

Comment: @l4mpi, Bakuriu is correct, all triplets should be taken into account, and of course wihtout altering the fundamental structure of the algorithm, it should stay brute force

Comment: Ah, I must've missed that... in that case it would be better to use [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) in a generator expression similar to the one above: `cnt = sum(1 for p in permutations(a, 3) if not sum(p))`

Comment: @l4mpi, but the algorithm cannot change, you should iterate in the same way without altering elements order, otherwise you would have a different algorithm.

Comment: @l4mpi To be fair, that's substantially the same as saying "write this code in C instead". (A valid approach, and arguably the recommended one for this sort of numbercrunchey code, although it doesn't explain the slowdown.)

Comment: I don't think we're going anywhere using any kind of trick here. The huge performance difference we see is due to the fact that Java's JIT can optimize that loop to something equivalent to a simple C for loop which uses only a bunch of machine instructions. Python iterations are **much** heavier. The only way to obtain similar results is to avoid completely the iteration at python level using some built-in, but I don't think there is any built-in that will allow you to do that. You should try to run the java program without JIT, if it's possible, to compare the interpreted timings.

Comment: @Peter `itertools.permutations` should be the same algorithm, modulo order of results.

Comment: The problem with the permutation "trick" here is, that here, this happens to be a permutation indeed, but in other loops, this might not be the case, making this runtime environment possibly a bad choice to study algorithms I'm afraid.  I cannot follow the textbooks examples without loosing until days of waiting..

Comment: @millimoose well the slowdown is due to the fact that list access and explicit for loops are way slower in python than in java; but nobody who knows their way around a python shell would write an algorithm that way. Peter, even for educational purposes you shouldn't do straight ports of java code to python, use the high level tools python gives you to write much more elegant algorithms. Your other loops might have other elegant python solutions that are impossible in java; and even more elegant solutions in lisp or haskell or prolog. You wouldn't do a straight port to these languages either.

Comment: @l4mpi : thanks for your elaboration, I appreciate it.  Also the pypy solution only solved the problem (see update in the benchmarks in the question)

Comment: Take into account that PyPy run faster only on some kind of algorithms. If you are dealing with long-integer arithmetic, for example, CPython is faster. Anyway, what you should deduce from this benchmarking is that JITs can provide a big increase in performance, not that CPython is generally slow. You could try to run your algorithm on CPython using [`psycho`](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) and you'll probably see results similar to PyPy.(unfortunately it's not maintained anymore).

Comment: @Bakuriu, one thing is sure : learned a lot with this question :-) thank you all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running it with PyPy instead of CPython.  It will very likely go much faster.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented the function in C and PHP also. Here is the result:

**PHP**: 23.977946043015 sec 
**Python**: 19.31 sec

**C**: 0.4 sec
**Java**: 0.42 sec

We are looking at language with different type system. PHP and Python are dynamically typed whereas C and Java are statically typed.

So, the PHP and Python interpreter spends a lot of time guessing the type of the variables used and hence run very slow. Whereas in C and Java, the type of variables (and the elements of array) are static i.e integer and hence the guessing time is saved. And apparently, this guessing time is too high as you can see from the numbers above.

With PyPY, the guessing time is dramatically reduced because PyPY uses Just In Time(JIT) compilation. This method is very good at guessing the type of the variable used and hence you get the performance bump.

Comment: +1 : not quite an answer, but I like benchmarks that I don't have to write :-)

Comment: Trying to put some stuff from computer science into perspective :D
Btw, size of array is 1000.

Comment: -1: "So, the PHP and Python interpreter spends a lot of time guessing the type of the variables used and hence run very slow" - this is patently wrong and misleading. Python doesn't guess the types of anything, every object has a known type. While it's true that part of the overhead is caused by the lack of compile-time type information (or a tracing JIT) prevents CPython from gaining the level of performance usual for statically typed languages, it does not "guess types" anywhere. In fact, the reason why PyPy is faster is that it makes an educated guess as to what the types of variables are!

Comment: -1 : *"...but I like benchmarks that I don't have to write"* - OTOH, benchmark results that other people can't reproduce ('cos nobody but the author has the source code) are worthless.

Comment: -1: This is utter bullshit. Types cannot be guessed, because data has no inherent type, its all the same. How could Python throw a TypeError, if it didn't know the types of variables?

PHP and Python are interpreted, which is where the slowness comes from. Most statically typed languages are compiled, but thats just a coincidence. For example Common Lisp is compiled and dynamically typed.

Answer (score 2):

As already said in the comments of your start post, there is no good way to make this much faster (besides PyPy). You can try islice, which will iterate over "a" and not make new lists or ranges, this should be a litte faster.

```
from itertools import islice

def count(a):
    cnt = 0
    for x, i in enumerate(islice(a,0, None)): 
        for y, j in enumerate(islice(a, x + 1, None)):
            for k in islice(a, y + x + 2, None):
                if i + j + k == 0:
                   cnt+=1
    return cnt
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked that yourself? In my case it's a whole lot slower (in pypy : 50 seconds in stead of 4 for an array of 2K elements)

Comment: i benchmarked it with python 2.7.3 (no pypy), 1.4 sec vs. 1.1 sec with islice and a smaller test list than 2000

Comment: I'v got 2 sec versus 1 sec indeed using regular python, using pypy however : 0.1 sec versus 0.5 seconds, so 5 times slower, strange : in pypy this method is a lot slower than the regular one, but still faster than the fastes in regular python...

Answer (score 0):

For Python use itertools combination in the standard library, it'll move the for loops to C.