# 3-Sum Java to Python conversion

Tags: java, python

I am trying to convert this Java(I think) code into Python.

From:

```
    public class ThreeSum
    {
    public static int count(int[] a)
    {
        int N = a.length;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int j = i+1; k < N; j++)
                for (int k = j+1; k<N; k++)
                    if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0)
                        count++;
        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = In.readInts(args[0]);
        StdOut.printIn(count(a));
    }
    }
```

To:

```
a = [30,-40,-20,-10,40,0,10,5]
def check(list):
    N = len(list)
    count = 0
    i = 0
    while i < N:
        i += 1
        j = i+1
        while j < N:
            j += 1
            k = j+1
            while k < N:
                k += 1
                if a[i]+a[j]+a[k] == 0: #<-- this is the main part with error "list index out of range"
                    count += 1
    return count
    print count
check(a)
```

It's supposed to check all the numbers in the list how many sums of 3 pairs equals 0.
I'm not sure what to use instead of "for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)". I think my while loops do the same thing, or am I wrong?

Comment: The direct Python equivalent of `for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)` is `for i in xrange(N):` Your Python code does not do the same thing as the Java for loops because you increment in the beginning of your loop body (as opposed to incrementing at the end). It is also pointless to have a print statement after a return statement.

Comment: As a side note, this can be written as a 1-liner: `return sum(1 for i in range(n) for j in range(i, n) for k in range(j, n) if a[i]+a[j]+a[k] == 0)`. Whether that's more idiomatic or more readable… well, I can't tell when it's in a comment without formatting. :)

Comment: PS, kudos for not creating a useless `ThreeSum` class and making this a `@staticmethod`, as many people would do when trying to convert Java to Python.

Comment: In `for (int j = i+1; k < N; j++)` you probably want `j < N` as a stop condition.

Comment: [This has come up before.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712596/why-is-the-map-version-of-threesum-so-slow/25713282#comment40203375_25713282) [And again.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922014/python-very-slow-as-compared-to-java-for-this-algorithm) It's probably some standard homework, now. One thing I *beg* you to do is not make any guesses about speed without looking at the first link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `for` statement can only loop over an iterable. So, if you want to loop over a range of numbers, you use a `range` object as an iterable. So, this Java:

```
for (int k = j+1; k<N; k++)
```

… becomes this Python:

```
for k in range(j+1, N):
```

It's worth nothing that in many cases, you don't actually want to do this; if the only thing you're going to use `k` for is `a[k]`, you can just iterate over `a` itself. However, in this particular case, you need `i` and `j` to set the limits of `j` and `k`. (You could still write your loops with `enumerate`, but I think that would just get in the way here.)

So, the whole thing can be:

```
N = len(a)
count = 0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        for k in range(j+1, N):
            if a[i]+a[j]+a[k] == 0:
                count += 1
return count
```

---

However, I think this would be cleaner if you turned it into a generator-transformation pipeline:

```
N = len(a)
sums = (a[i]+a[j]+a[k] 
        for i in range(N) for j in range(i+1, N) for k in range(j+1, N))
zeros = (n for n in sums if n == 0)
return sum(1 for _ in zeros)
```

Or, if you want to code-golf it, taking advantage of the fact that `True` and `False` are `1` and `0` when used as integers:

```
N = len(a)
return sum(not a[i]+a[j]+a[k]
           for i in range(N) for j in range(i+1, N) for k in range(j+1, N))
```

---

But once you're thinking in these terms, is there a way to generate all of those `a[i]`, `a[j]`, and `a[k]` in a single step? Yes, those are just all of the possible combinations of 3 elements from `a`. Thanks for @alfasin for figuring this out before me, and writing it up a lot more concisely than I ever could. :) So:

```
combs = itertools.combinations(a)
sums = map(sum, combs)
zerosums = (n for n in sums if n == 0)
return sum(1 for _ in zerosums)
```

Or, code-golfing again:

```
return sum(not sum(c) for c in itertools.combinations(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a different approach:

```
from itertools import combinations
a = [30,-40,-20,-10,40,0,10,5]
combs = combinations(a, 3) 
s = 0
for c in combs:
    x, y, z = c
    if x + y + z == 0:
        print x, y, z
        s += 1

print "number of combinations that sum to zero:", s
```

**OUTPUT**

```
30 -40 10
30 -20 -10
-40 40 0
-10 0 10

number of combinations that sum to zero: 4
```

Comment: He just wants to count them, so you can make this even simpler: `if sum(comb): count += 1`.